# extract month from a character year and doy in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

Given a year and a day (in Julian day), how can I extract the month? For e.g.

```
Year <- '2000'
Doy  <- '159'
```

I want to extract the month for the above Year and Doy. I thought first I will convert this into date and then extract the month out of it using `format(mydate,"%m")`

```
# first convert into date and then extract the month  
as.Date(paste0(Year'-',Doy), format = '%Y-%d')
NA
```

This gives me NA.

Comment: Looks like you're just missing a comma in `paste0(Year,'-',Doy)`, fixing that works for me.

`> as.Date(paste0(Year,'-',Doy), format = '%Y-%d')
[1] "2000-04-15"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%d is for day of month.  %j is for day of year where Jan 1 is day of year 1, Jan 2 is day of year 2, ..., Dec 31 is day of year 365 (or 366 on leap years).  See ?strptime for the percent codes.

```
Year <- '2000'
Doy  <- '159'

date <- as.Date(paste(Year, Doy), format = "%Y %j"); date
## [1] "2000-06-07"

as.numeric(format(date, "%m")) # month number
## [1] 6
```